# How can I plot trajectories of change in ordination space?

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to plot trajectories of change in palaeoecological data. Firstly, I used metaMDS in vegan to produce a list of NMDS coordinates, this was successful.

Then I used the [ecotraj](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecotraj/index.html) package to try to plot the trajectories but got an error message. Can anyone help me figure out what the error message means? I would like to plot trajectories for 12 sites in total. Many thanks.

```
sites<- NMDS_coords[c(1)]
time<- NMDS_coords[c(2)]
D<- NMDS_coords[c(3,4)]

trajectoryPCoA(D, sites, time,
               survey.labels = T)
```

error message:

```
Error in cmdscale(D2, eig = TRUE, add = TRUE, k = nrow(as.matrix(D2)) -  : 
  'k' must be in {1, 2, ..  n - 1}
```

Here is an example of my data:

[First 20 rows of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHIlE.png).
Data from the first 3 sites is available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/115HyULmkrr_zZ5Nh7PcgfcrVyzrpmyGdVZMy0wkXkxg/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: The error message means that you (or trajectoryPCoA) asked for too many axes: the limit is number of rows - 1. I don't think you can extract your data with that indexing. You should probably use NMDS_coords[, 1], NMDS_coords[, 2], NMDS_coords[, c(3,4)] - that is, to use column indexing (second index, after comma). If NMDS is from vegan, why don't you plot the trajectory directly to the NMDS plot using vegan::ordiarrows instead of going through PCoA of NMDS?

Comment: Thanks so much Jari! I used ordiarrows instead. Thanks for your helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on using ordiarrows (vegan package). I plotted the trajectories of PCA rather than NMDS. Note that I log transformed the data before I did the rda.

```
data= log(data+1)

mod<-rda(data)
plot(mod, type = "n")
plot<-ordiarrows(mod, site_vector, label = TRUE, col = c(1:3), show.groups = c("1", "2", "3"))
title("PCA trajectories")
legend("topright",
       title = "Site", 
       legend("topleft", c("Site 1 Tonga", "Site 2 Fiji", "Site 3 Tonga"), lty = 1, col = c(1:3)))
```

[PCA trajectories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yfeC.png)